# How to create a condition for scrolling below a point, and fire the function just once. instead of every time you scroll below that point

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make the header fade out, then slide back in when you scroll past 100px, but the function fires every time you scroll anywhere past that point.

I don't want that to happen, I want it so that the function fires only once when you scroll past it and if you scroll again, even if you're past that point, nothing happens.

Check out my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bazzle/6ykyjm0p/2/

Thanks in advance.

```
<header>
    <div class="top">
        This is the header
    </div>
    This is the point function should work.
</header>
```

```css
html {
    height: 200%;
}
header {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}
.top{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    display: block;
}
```

```js
var stickyheader = function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('header').hide(50, function(){
            $(this).slideDown(1000);
        });
    }
    else {
    }
};

$(window).on('scroll',function(){
    stickyheader();
});
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Your code hides the `header` then immediately slides it down again, making it re-appear...?

Comment: Exactly. I will also add a class to make it static via addClass.
Basically, I want the header to disappear, and reappear in a fixed position at the top, when you scroll past it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can use a global variable as a flag to prevent the script from firing.

```js
var flag = 0;
var stickyheader = function() {

 if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
  if (flag == 0) {
   $('header').hide(50, function() {
    $(this).slideDown(1000);
    flag = 1;
   });
  }
 } else {

 }

};

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
 stickyheader();
});
```

```css
html {
    height:200%;
}
header {
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
}
.top {
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    border-bottom:1px solid white;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <div class="top">This is the header</div>This is the point function should work.</header>
```

You can also reset `flag = 0;` in the else case if you want the code to execute everytime the user scroll beyond the point.
Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks! works a treat.
Here's the updated fidde with the addClass to make it static.

http://jsfiddle.net/bazzle/6ykyjm0p/5/